# How to display user's ssh public key?

Tags: ssh

What is the one-line command that can display the first 20 characters of a user's ssh public key. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one line and it shows the first 20 characters of public key if you give the correct path:

```
cut -b 20 /path/to/user/key
```